# Forward stability

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am studying forward stability. My book proposes this exercise: find an algorithm to calculate
$\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$ when $x \approx 0$ and prove its forward stability. I think one answer could be using the Taylor expansion. Are there any algorithms that are more elegant to use? I have tried to find them out but I wasn't able.
Thank you in advance for the help. I expect you to give me only a pice of advice!

Comment: Actually using the trigonometric identities works quite well, $f(x)=2(\frac{\sin(x/2)}x)^2$ for $x\ne 0$ gives correct results as $\sin(u)$ evaluates to $u(1+O(u^2))$ to the given numerical precision. Now this is an atypical situation, the next derivative would be a different story, for instance $\frac{\sin(x)-x\cos(x)}{x^3}$ has not such a simple improved expression. Also the sine evaluation at points different than $0$ does not have this behavior, so $\frac{1-\cos(x)}{(x-2\pi)^2}$ for $x\approx 2\pi$ will be more difficult. There you need Taylor series and some experiments to reduce jumps.

Comment: Has your class covered Horner's method for evaluating polynomials? Specifically, do you have a forward error bound for this method which you can apply?

Comment: What is the problem with $\sin^2x/[x^2(1+\cos x)]$? It certainly helps with catastrophic cancellation for $x\approx 0$.